# Problem with stack order in VB6: object block not responsive to ZOrder

Tags: vb6

In a fairly complex program, I'm failing to get a label to appear above a frame and checkboxes.

I've tried:

1. setting the label's ZOrder to 0 and the frame's to 1 in the frame's dragover
2. manually editing the relative order of definitions in the form's frm file

Of interest is that most any other newly added object (textbox, picturebox, checkbox, frame, command button) **is** shown above the frame, but not a new label.  [Also shapes, lines, and a few others]

The code for the Frame is pretty tame:

```
Begin VB.Frame Frame4
  BackColor       =   &H00E8A2A2&
  Caption         =   "Repertoire"
  Height          =   2055
  Left            =   8400
  TabIndex        =   150
  Top             =   1080
  Width           =   1980
End
```

The label is drawn over other objects on the form.
Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Labels, lines and a few others are "lightweight controls". They don't have a hwnd and are not real windows. They are drawn on their parent.

Comment: Is it possible to hack a label to be a child of a frame then?

Comment: You don't have to hack it. Just place it there.

Comment: Answer to my Q: Placing it there has to be done a specific way, explained (at least) here: https://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/label-frame-controls.html. To make an existing control a child of a Frame control, select the control, press Ctrl+X to cut it, select the Frame control, and press Ctrl+V to paste the control inside the Frame. The label will now be a child of the frame, and appear over it.

Comment: You can also draw the control on the container: single click the label in the toolbox, then left click-and-drag on the frame. Label will be a child of the frame. The label will, of course, have the height and width values of the drawn control (not the defaults when the toolbox control is double clicked), adjust as necessary.

Comment: @murspieg you can actually just answer your own question here, by adding a proper answer. Go for it if you think you've solved the issue.